# Подключение к виртуальному Android серверу с Windows

Tags: android, android-studio, сервер, virtualbox, genymotion

В Windows установлен Genymotion (что-то вроде обёртки над VirtualBox).
В Genymotion установлен Android, в Android установлен и запущен сервис с функционалом сервера.
Через браузер в самом Android есть возможность подключения к серверу, а вот с Windows подключится уже не получается (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT или ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED).
Подключение идет по адресу http://192.168.126.107/ этот же адрес используется в ADB, поэтому я предположил что это как бы внешний адрес Android.
В VirtualBox в настройках сети, пробовал пробрасивать порты. Это ничего не дало.
Подскажите как можно реализовать подключение или узнать правильный адрес если это не он http://192.168.126.107/.

Comment: Покажите маршруты на винде. И раз это виртуалка, большая вероятность того, что ARP пакеты могут резаться. Как включить `proxy arp` для этой виртуалки, и нужно ли включать читайте в интернете.